# Extract columns from multiple text files with bash or awk or sed?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to extract column1 and column4 from multiple text files.

file1.txt:

```
#rname  startpos        endpos  numreads        covbases        coverage        meandepth       meanbaseq       meanmapq
CFLAU10s46802|kraken:taxid|33189        1       125     2       105     84      1.68    36.8    24
CFLAU10s46898|kraken:taxid|33189        1       116     32      116     100     23.5862 35.7    19.4
CFLAU10s46988|kraken:taxid|33189        1       105     2       53      50.4762 1.00952 36.9    11
AUZW01004514.1 Cronartium comandrae C4 contig1015102_0, whole genome shotgun sequence   1       1102    2       88      7.98548 0.15971 36.4    10
AUZW01004739.1 Cronartium comandrae C4 contig1070682_0, whole genome shotgun sequence   1       2133    6       113     5.2977  0.186592        36.6    13
```

file2.txt:

```
#rname  startpos        endpos  numreads        covbases        coverage        meandepth       meanbaseq       meanmapq
CFLAU10s46802|kraken:taxid|33189        1       125     5       105     84      1.68    36.8    24
CFLAU10s46898|kraken:taxid|33189        1       116     40      116     100     23.5862 35.7    19.4
CFLAU10s46988|kraken:taxid|33189        1       105     6       53      50.4762 1.00952 36.9    11
AUZW01004514.1 Cronartium comandrae C4 contig1015102_0, whole genome shotgun sequence   1       1102    2       88      7.98548 0.15971 36.4    10
AUZW01004739.1 Cronartium comandrae C4 contig1070682_0, whole genome shotgun sequence   1       2133    6       113     5.2977  0.186592        36.6    13
```

output format (save the output as merged.txt in another directory). In the output file: Column1(#nname) will be once because this is same for every file, but there will be multiple column4 (numreads) as many as files and the rename the column4 should be according to each file name.
Output file looks like:

```
#rname  file1_numreads     file2_numreads
CFLAU10s46802|kraken:taxid|33189        2       5
CFLAU10s46898|kraken:taxid|33189       32      40
CFLAU10s46988|kraken:taxid|33189        2       6
AUZW01004514.1 Cronartium comandrae C4 contig1015102_0, whole genome shotgun sequence   2       88
AUZW01004739.1 Cronartium comandrae C4 contig1070682_0, whole genome shotgun sequence   6       113
```

Your suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What's the problem you're having? If the columns are delimited by tabs, set FS to tab in awk, to split them. If the column delimiter is the same as the word delimiter in column 1 (ie. spaces), you'll have to match the numeric columns with regex.

Comment: Yeah, the input file format is broken, unless it is `<TAB>` delimited?

Comment: I just replace the real file, it seems tab delimbed file, could you suggest the code now?

Comment: Can we assume that column 1 values are always present in both files, and in the same order?

Comment: @abs Try something yourself first. At the very least try to extract the targeted columns with `sed` or `awk` or `cut` or `read` or whatever

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I put together.  `awk` gurus might have a simpler - shorter version but I am still learning `awk`.

Create a file `script.awk` and make it executable.  Put in it:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="\t" }

# process files, ignoring comments
!/^#/ {
    # keep the first column values.
    # Only add a new value if it is not already in the array.
    if (!($1 in firstcolumns)) {
        firstcolumns[$1] = $1
    }
    # extract the 4th column of file1, put it in the array (column 1).1
    if (FILENAME == ARGV[1]) {
        results[$1 ".1"] = $4
    }
    # extract the 4th column of file2, put it in the array (column 1).2
    if (FILENAME == ARGV[2]) {
        results[$1 ".2"] = $4
    }
}

# print the results
END {
    # for each first column value...
    for (key in firstcolumns) {
        # Print the first column, then (column 1).1, then (column 1).2
        print key "\t" results[key ".1"] "\t" results[key ".2"]
    }
}
```

- Call it like this: `./script.awk file1.txt file2.txt`.
- Since `awk` parses the files line per line, I keep the possible values of the first column in an array (firstcolumns).
- For each line, if the 4th column comes from file1.txt (ARGV[1]) I store it in the results array under (firstcolumn).1.
- For each line, if the 4th column comes from file2.txt (ARGV[2]) I store it in the results array under (firstcolumn).2.
- In the END block, loop through the possible firstcolumn values and print the values (firstcolumn).1 and (firstcolumn).2, separated by "\t" for tabs.

Results:

```
$ ./so.awk file1.txt file2.txt
AUZW01004514.1  C4  C4
CFLAU10s46988|kraken:taxid|33189    2   6
CFLAU10s46802|kraken:taxid|33189    2   5
AUZW01004739.1  C4  C4
CFLAU10s46898|kraken:taxid|33189    32  40
```

Comment: You need to set `FS` to `\t`

Comment: Yes indeed, I copy paste the sample files, so I was using spaces.